# Find the best fitting line on a 2d scatterplot. In C++

Tags: c++, computer-vision, ransac

How to find a line of a certain length in a scatter plot.

I have a set of points and i want to find a line of length 1 that best fits the data.

Visually you can easily identify it. But how do I find this with C++?

RANSAC seems to be the right solution, based on this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus But i'm looking for the best fitting line of fixed length.

[image: Scatter plot]

Here is a file with sample data. https://gist.github.com/apkuhar/d9d5b50808e44ee0a86ef4b0f657e9c0

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be the following algorithm:

1. DBSCAN clustering.
2. For each cluster, compute PCA. Clusters that have most of their variance in the first PCA component (2nd component is near zero) form lines.
3. Fit a line through the cluster with the smallest 2nd PCA component.

Though you'd have to be careful to eliminate clusters that are too small. DBSCAN will typically consider groups of few points as outliers, and not make them into a cluster. But since you require a minimum length, you can impose that requirement on the clusters before picking the one that most looks like a line. For example, find the largest distance within the cluster, and select clusters where this distance is at least your minimum line length.